# What is the proper syntax for running python code on terminal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal

The name of my file is Step1.py and it is meant to open a page on google maps. I'm running El Capitan on a macbook air. It's saved in my home file and I gave it the permissions it needs (I think).
Here's Step1.py:

```
#! 

import pprint
import webbrowser
def launchweb(location):
   web = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/'
   location = input('Gimmi Yo Adress: ')
   rlocation = (location.replace(',', ''))
   rlocation = rlocation.split()
   for i in range(len(rlocation)):
      if i != len(rlocation) - 1:
          rlocation[i] = rlocation[i] + '+'
   for i in rlocation:
      web = web + i
   return web
webbrowser.open(launchweb(12))
```

I entered `chmod +x Step1.py` into the terminal, then I tried to run `python ./Step1.py`

It promted an address, and I entered one `Gimmi Yo Adress: 1234 fake st, san fransisco, ca`

Then it gave me this:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./Step1.py", line 16, in <module>
     webbrowser.open(launchweb(12))
   File "./Step1.py", line 7, in launchweb
     location = input('Gimmi Yo Adress: ')
   File "<string>", line 1
     1234 fake st, san fransisco, ca
             ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the proper syntax?

Comment: you want `rawinput()` or whatever it's called

Comment: Your problem is not the operating system or the terminal. You are calling `input`, which is trying to evaluate the string as python syntax.

Comment: `raw_input()`, indeed.

Comment: Also, `chmod` is not needed if you do `python script.py`

Comment: Also, `(location.replace(',', ''))` does not need parens; `rlocation[i] += '+'` and `web += i` although `i` is a bad name for a string and is an overloaded variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting you address in quotes.

Gimmi Yo Adress: "1234 fake st, san fransisco, ca"

There are more issues, but I will leave that to you. It should open.

Comment: Worked Great! Thanks!!